# WooCommerce Payment Gateways for Logged In Customers Only

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

i want to show "cash on delivery" gateway payment for logged users only. The loop code where show the available payments is this:

```
<ul class="payment_methods methods">
    <?php
        if ( $available_gateways = $woocommerce->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways() ) {
            // Chosen Method
            if ( sizeof( $available_gateways ) )
                current( $available_gateways )->set_current();

            foreach ( $available_gateways as $gateway ) {
                ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" <?php if ($gateway->chosen) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
                    <label for="payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>"><?php echo $gateway->get_title(); ?> <?php echo $gateway->get_icon(); ?></label>
                    <?php
                        if ( $gateway->has_fields() || $gateway->get_description() ) {
                            echo '<div class="payment_box payment_method_' . $gateway->id . '" style="display:none;">';
                            $gateway->payment_fields();
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
        } else {

            echo '<p>'.__( 'Sorry, it seems that there are no available payment methods for your location. Please contact us if you require assistance or wish to make alternate arrangements.', 'woocommerce' ).'</p>';

        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mean using something like this:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... } ?>
```

If you already know the gateway ID i guess you can play with some if conditionals.

Comment: thanks rgdesign for your answer, but i dont know where to put your code... My code example show the loop where the template put all the gateways. Can you guide me where put your code? Sorry for my regular english, im from argentina. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, me from uruguay!, but is better to use english here, if not many people will not understand and comments and answers will be unusable for community.

Anyway, the is_user_logged_in will return true if the user is logged in, as functions says.

You have already the $gateway->id; **inside the foreach loop**. So, you need to condition the visibility for certain $gateway->id; if the user is logged in; something like this:

```
if($gateway->id == 123 && is_user_logged_in()){
   // something if user logged in and your gateway id
} else {
   // something else
}
```

You need to change 123 to your gateway id... also, i don´t know, but you can get the gateway name or slug and use that spite id. Try it.

Suerte!